# Finding the coefficient of $x^4$ in this expansion

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I’ve spent some time on this question that i have and am a bit stumped, i am a bit rusty when it comes to maths and my algebra and i am unsure about how i should find the coefficient of $x^4$ in this expansion.

The question:

> Find the coefficient of $x^4$ in the expansion of: $$x(x^2 + 2x + 3)(x^2 + 7x - 2)$$

Basically I want to know what method i would use to find this coefficient and why.

Thanks guys.

Comment: Expand $(x^2 + 2x + 3)(x^2 + 7x - 2)$ and find the coefficient of $x^3$

Comment: as suggested above just multiply those terms that have $x^3$, then $x^2.7x+2x.x^2=9x^3$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the detailed slow method, then you shall expand the product term by term.

Let's start with the two brackets:

$$x(x^4 + 7x^3 - 2x^2 + 2x^3 + 14x^2 - 4x + 3x^2 + 21x - 6)$$

Obtained multiplying term by term in the two brackets.

Arranging:

$$x(x^4 + 9x^3 + 15x^2 + 17x - 6)$$

Now time for the last multiplication:

$$x^5 + 9x^4 + 15x^3 + 17x^2 - 6x$$

Which means the coefficient of $x^4$ is $\boxed{9}$

Comment: Thanks Beta! this is what i was looking for, been a while since i've done stuff like this

Comment: @A.Kennedy No problem! I thought indeed you wanted the whole expansion. Try to do lots of those to get the velocity/ability again! I bet you will without too much effort :)

Comment: Thanks! but i have just one question, how did you get 7x^3 in the first bracket?

Comment: @A.Kennedy When you have an expression like $(a + b + c)\cdot (e + f + g)$ you have to multiply each term in the first fracked by each term in the second. So the expansion would be:

$$ae + af + ag + be + bf + bg + ce + cf + cg$$

In that case $7x^3$ comes from the first term in the first bracket, $x^2$ by the second term in the second brace, $7x$, so $x^2\cdot 7x = 7x^3$

Comment: Ah yes, thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

There is not a spacial method you can just multiple it in terms of  ${ x }^{ 4 } $$$x\left( { x }^{ 2 }+2x+3 \right) \left( { x }^{ 2 }+7x-2 \right) =\left( { x }^{ 3 }+2{ x }^{ 2 }+3x \right) \left( { x }^{ 2 }+7x-2 \right) =...+7{ x }^{ 4 }+2{ x }^{ 4 }+..=9{ x }^{ 4 }$$

Answer (score 0):

The coefficient you're looking for is the coefficient in $x^3$ in $(x^2 + 2x + 3)(x^2 + 7x - 2)$.

The only way to get $x^3$ is multiplying the $x^2$ of one bracket with the $kx$ of the other.

The obvious result is $7+2=9$